# Custom Class raises error when trying to call fit_transform

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, python-3.6, sklearn-pandas

I have created custom classes that want to use with scikit-learn Pipelines and Feature-Unions.

Each class takes as input a data frame with 2 columns: 0, 1

Each row in the first column is a numpy array, and each row in the second row is a number.

Given these two inputs, I have created a static function that calculates **for each row** of the data-frame 40 values.

So if the original data-frame is of shape 100 x 2 the output should be 100 x 40.

I've used the BaseEstimator and TransformerMixin modules to handle the fit_transform methods easily.

When I call the fit_transform method I get the following error:

**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (288, 40), indices imply (288, 2)**

```
class MelFrequencyCepstralCoefficientsCalculator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """outputs Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients"""

    def __init__(self):
        """

        """

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_coef(file_array: np.array,
                       sample_rate):
        """

        :param file_array:
        :param sample_rate:
        :return:
        """
        # mfcc: Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients to each row

        # this output is an array of shape (40, )
        mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=file_array,
                                             sr=sample_rate,
                                             n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
        return mfccs

    def transform(self, X, y=None) -> np.array:
        print('Calculating Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients')

        res = X.progress_apply(lambda row: self.calculate_coef(row[0], row[1]), axis=1).values

        print('Output shape: {}'.format(res.shape))

        return res

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """Returns `self` unless something different happens in train and test"""
        return self

mfccs = MelFrequencyCepstralCoefficientsCalculator()

x_val = mfccs.fit_transform(x_val_raw)
```

Shouldn't I be able to have a custom class that creates more than one features in a sklearn Pipeline?

PS: The **progress_appy** is valid. I'm using tqdm module that extends **apply** in order to have a progress bar for each calculation

The workaround that is much slower but works is the following:

```
    def transform(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y=None) -> np.array:
    """

    :param X:
    :param y:
    :return:
    """
    print('Calculating Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients')

    # res = X.apply(lambda row: self.calculate_coef(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)

    features = np.empty((0, 40))

    rows = X.iterrows()

    for row in tqdm(rows):
        ext_features = self.calculate_coef(row[1][0], row[1][1])
        features = np.vstack([features, ext_features])

    print('Output shape: {}'.format(features.shape))

    return features
```

Comment: I take that the original shape  of x_val_raw = 100 x 2? What is the shape of X in the transform function? Try to log that. Also the shape of 'res'.

Comment: Show how you are using that in the pipeline

Comment: @tvgriek The original shape as I mention is some_number X 2 . The nature of the problem is that I cannot perform an "apply" method to two different columns in order to obtain an array of 40 values as output for each row

Comment: @VivekKumar Like this:
`combined_features = FeatureUnion(
            [
                ('mfccs', MelFrequencyCepstralCoefficientsCalculator()),
                ('tonnetz', TonalCentroidFeaturesCalculator()),
                ('chroma', ChromaSTFTCalculator()),
                ('mel', MelScaledPowerSpectrogramCalculator()),
                ('contrast', SpectralContrastCalculator())
            ])

        self.pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
            ('feats', combined_features),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler())
        ])
`

Comment: There are other classes here also. Please provide [a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible